# Is there a way to push existing text left while inserting (e.g., insert right-aligned text)?

Tags: insert-mode, formatting, alignment

In insert mode, typing normally moves the cursor right and pushes text to the right of the cursor farther to the right on the line.  I am typing some right-aligned text and am wondering - is there a way to tell vim to leave the cursor where it is while inserting, and move text *preceding* the cursor to the *left*?  (Discarding whatever falls off the beginning of the line is fine.)  I can't find a way on SO or wikia, and there may not be one, but I thought I'd check.

The closest thing I have found is `gR<Ctl-D>` ([virtual replace mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#vreplace-mode)), but that lets me blithely overwrite what is past the cursor position where I started.

Use case: I have this situation:

```
<line of source code that does something> <tricky part>
        comment explaining tricky part(*) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and want to add text at the place marked `(*)` without moving the `^^^^^^^^^^^^^`, by pushing `comment explaining tricky part` to the left.

Comment: I'm not sure that would be a good solution but according to `:help arabic` it is possible to write text right aligned when the option `+arabic` is enabled, maybe you could search for something this way... (Also I tend to think that if your purpose is just commenting code, you might not need a right-aligned presentation and write it in a regular way but thats only my opinion ;-) )

Comment: @statox `set rightleft` does that, but that also means that everything is reversed; so  `Hello, world` becomes `dlrow ,olleH` ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Oh I didn't know that but that makes sense... Actually that's why I made it a comment and not an answer because that was just a thought and I never used it :-)

Answer (score 6):

(EDITED version)

```
"============ in your vimrc =================

command! TogglePush  :call TogglePush()
inoremap <Insert> <Esc>:TogglePush<CR>a
nnoremap <Insert> :TogglePush<CR>

command! EnablePush  :call EnablePush()
command! DisablePush :call DisablePush()

"============= in a script file =============

let s:push_enabled = 0
function! TogglePush()
    if (s:push_enabled)
        call DisablePush()
        let s:push_enabled = 0
        echo "PUSH disabled"
    else
        call EnablePush()
        let s:push_enabled = 1
        echo "PUSH enabled"
    endif
endfunction

function! DisablePush()
    augroup PushLeft
        autocmd!
    augroup END
    let s:push_enabled = 0
endfunction

function! EnablePush()
    augroup PushLeft
        autocmd!
        autocmd TextChangedI * call AfterChange()
    augroup END
    let s:push_enabled = 1
    let s:cursor_column = getpos(".")[2]
endfunction


let s:cursor_column = -1

function! AfterChange()
    let l = getline(".")
    let lnum = getpos(".")[1]
    let c = getpos(".")[2] "get cursor column
    let col_diff = c - s:cursor_column
    if (col_diff > 0) " at actual text insertion
        call setline('.', strpart(getline('.'), col_diff))
    else
        let filler = ''
        while col_diff < 0
            let filler .= ' '
            let col_diff += 1
        endwhile
        call setline('.', filler . getline('.'))
    endif
        call cursor(lnum, s:cursor_column)
endfunction
```

This is a somewhat improved version of the original answer. When you enable the push (in the example below, pressing the `Insert` key, or with `:EnablePush` from vim cmd-line), the current column number is saved as the "pinned cursor column" position and an 'after-text-was-changed-in-insert-mode' event is enabled, that will try to keep the cursor on *that* column, and preserve the text *after* the cursor. The text *before* the cursor is altered like follows:

- if characters were added, all text before the cursor is moved to the *left*, and the characters at the beginning of the line disappear (i.e. they "fall" behind the left margin).
- if backspace was pressed, text before the cursor is moved to the *right*, by inserting `space` chars at line start.

*NOTES:*

- This adds a "pin cursor to column" functionality.
- If cursor doesn't seem to be on the right column, it means there are some real tabs on the left of the cursor, and what you *see* is the "virtual cursor" position (I didn't use `virtcol()` etc.).

Comment: I've tried this but `TextChangedI` doesn't seem to be firing.  I put the code in `~/vimfiles/plugin/pushleft.vim` and `~/vimfiles/vimrc`.  I started with `vim -u NONE` and manually sourced those two.  `:TogglePush` does print the enabled/disabled message, but text entry is normal even when push is enabled.  When I `set verbose=9`, I see `CursorMovedI` as text is entered.  When I hit Esc, I see `TextChanged`, but I never see `TextChangedI`.  Any thoughts?  Vim is `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 10 2013 14:33:40)`.  Thanks!