# Is there a source for pre-built patched Win32/Win64 vims?

Tags: microsoft-windows, installing

[Turns out](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.4/README) my problem with [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3781/1430) is that I need patch 7.4.143.  I can't find any download on vim.org for a Windows patched-vim installer.  Is there an official distribution of patched vim 7.4 for Windows?  [Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Where_to_download_Vim) says Vim without Cream is the way to go - is that indeed the one?  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps try this, is very recent: http://www.kaoriya.net/software/vim/ - one of  the Win32 / Win64 links. You'll have to remove `vimrc` and `gvimrc` from the main vim folder after extracting the archive. I use the 64bit version.

Comment: There are a few people that maintain up-to-date builds for Windows, you might want to ask about that on [vim_use](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vim_use).

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has really answered this question, here's my recommendation for installing the latest Vim on Windows.

[Official Vim website - download page](https://www.vim.org/download.php)

- My recommendation for getting Windows Vim.
- You can download the latest stable Vim installer `gvim##.exe` (ie `gvim81.exe`).

[Latest/ Nightly builds](https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases)

- Download page for latest nightly build installer
- Not recommended because build may not be stable, unless you need the absolute latest build.

[Tuxproject.de Windows Vim build](https://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/)

- Another Windows Vim build.
- However, some DLLs are not included, but they can be downloaded from the official Vim website download page (see above), called `vim##rt.zip` (ie `vim81rt.zip`)

If you are using Chocolatey package manager, I recommend `vim-tux` which is sourced from tuxproject.de:

```
choco install vim-tux -y
```

The other chocolatey package, `vim` has not been updated, and it seems that package maintenance has stalled.  Otherwise, you can install the older version using:

```
choco install vim -y
```